# Permutation of Actionscript 3 Array

Tags: actionscript-3

Greetings,

This is my first post and I hope someone out there can help. I am an educator and I designed a quiz using Actionscript 3 (Adobe Flash) that is to determine all the different ways a family can have three children.

I have two buttons that enter either the letter B (for boy) or G (for girl) into an input text field named text_entry. I then have a submit button named enter_btn that checks to see if the entry into the input text is correct. If the input is correct, the timeline moves to the next problem (frame labeled checkmark); if it is incorrect the timeline moves to the end of the quiz (frame 62).

The following code works well for any particular correct single entry (ie: BGB). I need to write code in which all eight correct variations must be entered, but they can be entered in any order (permutation):

ie:
BBB,BBG,BGB,BGG,GBB,GBG,GGB,GGG; or

BGB,GGG,BBG,BBB,GGB,BGB,GGB,BGG; or

GGB,GGG,BBG,BBB,GGB,BGB,BGB,BGG; etc...

there are over 40,000 ways to enter these eight ways of having three children. Help!

```
baby_B.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letterB);
function letterB(event:MouseEvent)
{
text_entry.appendText("B");
}

baby_G.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letterG);
function letterG(event:MouseEvent)
{
text_entry.appendText("G");
}

enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
function check(event:MouseEvent):void {
var solution_S:Array=["BBB","BBG","BGB","BGG","GBB","GBG","GGB","GGG "];

if(solution_S.indexOf(text_entry.text)>=0)
{
gotoAndStop("checkmark");
}
else
{
gotoAndPlay(62);
}
}
```

If you know the correct code, please write it out for me.  Thanks!

Comment: so is the user entering into 8 different inputs, or just one long string into the single input, or are you separating with commas...?  the solution is pretty simple, but i need to know what to test against (as regards user input).

Comment: An input can look like this: BBB, BBG, BGB, BGG, GBB, GBG, GGB, GGG (with commas): notice that there are eight "values" to enter at one time into the input text field. But these values do not have to be entered in this order. They can look something like this: BBG, GGB, BGB, GBG, GBB, GGG, BBB, BGG.

Comment: @user548228 - working sample provided as answer.  i kept as much of your existing code in place as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to keep a little bit of state to know what the user has entered so far. One possible way of doing that is to have a custom object/dictionary that you initialize outside all your functions, so that it is preserved during the transitions between frames/runs of the functions:

```
var solutionEntered:Object = {"BBB":false, "BBG":false, /*fill in rest */ };
```

Then in your function `check` you can perform an additional check, something like:

```
function check(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var solution_S:Array=["BBB","BBG","BGB","BGG","GBB","GBG","GGB","GGG "];
    if(solution_S.indexOf(text_entry.text)>=0) {
        // We know the user entered a valid solution, let's check if
        // then entered it before
        if(solutionEntered[text_entry.text]) {
            // yes they entered it before, do whatever you need to do
        } else {
            // no they haven't entered it, set the status as entered
            solutionEntered[text_entry.text] = true;
        }
        // continue rest of your function
     }
     // continue the rest of your function
 }
```

Note that this is not necessarily an optimal solution, but it keeps with the code style you already have.

Comment: This does just the opposite of what I originally had: previously I could enter any of the variations (ie: GGB) and my script accepted the solution as correct. now it accepts it as incorrect. I need all variations in any order to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var correctAnswers : Array = [ "BBB", "BBG", "BGB", "GBB", "BGG", "GGB", "GBG", "GGG" ];
var answersSoFar : Array;
var textField : TextField; //on stage
var submitButton : Sprite; //on stage
var correctAnswerCount : int;

//for testing
textField.text = "BBB,BBG,BGB,GBB,BGG,GGB,GBG,GGG"; 
//textField.text = "BGB,BBB,GGG,BBG,GBB,BGG,GGB,GBG,";
//textField.text = "BBB,BBG, BGB,GBB,BGG, GGB, GBG,   GGG";
//textField.text = "BBB,BBG,BGB,GBB,BGG,GGB,GBG"; 
//textField.text = "BBB,BBG,BGB,GBB,BGG,GGB,GBG,GGG,BBG"; 

submitButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onSubmit );

function onSubmit( event : MouseEvent ) : void
{
    var answers : Array = getAnswersArray( textField.text );

    answersSoFar = [];
    correctAnswerCount = 0;

    for each ( var answer : String in answers ) 
        if ( answerIsCorrect( answer ) ) correctAnswerCount++;

    if ( correctAnswerCount == correctAnswers.length ) trace( "correct" );
    else trace( "incorrect" );
}

function getAnswersArray( string : String ) : Array
{
    string = removeInvalidCharacters( string );
    return string.split( "," );
}

function removeInvalidCharacters( string : String ) : String
{
    var result : String = "";

    for ( var i : int, len = string.length; i < len; i++ )
        if ( string.charAt( i ) == "B" || string.charAt( i ) == "G" || string.charAt( i ) == "," )
            result += string.charAt( i );

    return result;
}

function answerIsCorrect( answer : String ) : Boolean
{
    if ( answerIsADuplicate( answer ) ) return false;
    else answersSoFar.push( answer );

if ( answerIsInListOfCorrectAnswers( answer ) ) return true;
    return false;
}

function answerIsInListOfCorrectAnswers( answer : String ) : Boolean
{
    if ( correctAnswers.indexOf( answer ) == -1 ) return false;
    return true;
}

function answerIsADuplicate( answer : String ) : Boolean
{
    if ( answersSoFar.indexOf( answer ) == -1 ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

note that in the original code you pasted, you have an extra space in the last element of your correct answer list - "GGG " should be "GGG"

this works

```
baby_B.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letterB);
function letterB(event:MouseEvent) {
    text_entry.appendText("B");
}

baby_G.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letterG);
function letterG(event:MouseEvent) {
    text_entry.appendText("G");
}

var valid:Array = ["BBB","BBG","BGB","BGG","GBB","GBG","GGB","GGG"];

enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
function check(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var parts:Array = text_entry.text.split(/,\s*/g);  // split the text into component parts
    var dup:Array = valid.slice();  // copy the correct list
    while(parts.length){  // run through each answer component
        var part:String = parts.pop();  // grab the last one
        part = part.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');  // strip leading/trailing white space
        var pos:int = dup.indexOf(part);  // is it in the list of correct answers?
        if(pos != -1){  // if it is...
            dup.splice(pos, 1);  // then remove that answer from the list
        }
    }
    if(dup.length == 0) {  // if it's 0, they got all the correct answers
        gotoAndStop("checkmark");
    } else {  // otherwise, they didn't get one or more correct answers
        gotoAndPlay(62);
    }
}
```